# Extracting links from XML file using python

Tags: python, regex

I have a sitemap XML file and I want to run a script which extracts all the urls and print it.
I have tried     re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', url)

but this prints the closing tags like : "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm /liv"

I don't want to print the suffix ' /liv ' how do I implement this using regex ?

Comment: What's wrong with using a XML parser?

Comment: Use an XML parser. XML must not be processed with regular expressions.

Comment: [**You should not use regex to process XML (or any other structured data)!**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7553525)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are all of the URLs wrapped in quotation marks or surrounded by spaces? If so, you could do something like:

```
re.findall(r'(?P<quote>.)(https?://\S+?)(?P=quote)', url)
```

If you're getting the string representation of everything matched, instead of just the second group, you'll have to trim it with `...[1:-1]`.